# Navigation settings missing in site settings. SharePoint Online

Tags: office365, sharepoint

I am an admin on all site collections and team sites which I created.

I need to change the Navigation method. However for some reason the new sites that I created does not give me the "Navigation" setting to do so but others it does. I'm sure it's something subtle but I can't seem to readily locate what I'm missing here.

Below are screen shots of team sites where I see the option in settings and where I do not see it.

> [image: No Navigation]
>
> [image: Yes Navigation]

Comment: -> Quick Launch

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to activate SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature on site collection level and SharePoint Server Publishing feature on site level. You get those Navigation settings by default when you create new sites with Publishing Site template.
Without it you're just left with "Quick Launch" & "Top Link Bar"
Cheers!